# Sugarcrm session timeout issue for different projects

Tags: php, .htaccess, sugarcrm

**Problem 1**: 
I have 4 projects of sugarcrm in one aws amazon instance, in this instance I have installed ubuntu operating system and installed `Apache`, `PHP`, `MySQL`. In my `/var/www/` path I have created 4 folder and installed sugarcrm in all folders and all are working fine. But my problem is when I login with project1 in one tab and login with project2 in another tab. My previous project1 site session is expiring.

I have kept different dir path in sugarcrm config file add below line and created session folder.

```
'session_dir' => 'session/',
```

**Problem 2**
In this sugarcrm 4 projects I am trying to increase session time , So in `php.ini` I have changed `"session.gc_maxlifetime = 30"` for testing purpose actually i need to change to `3600` in place of 30.

In htaccess I have add the below code also but no luck

```
IfModule mod_php5.c   
   #Session timeout        
   php_value session.cookie_lifetime 30   
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 30   
IfModule
```

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: you might have to put `php.ini` in all folders and set the session path differently for all projects, this way your sessions remain seperate

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me on production server on shared environment so I created a custom `php.ini` and separated my session path and it fixed the problem for me, so you might have to put php.ini in all project folders and set the session path differently for all projects, this way your sessions remain separate, this is how you can set session path in `php.ini`.

```
ini_set(session.save_path, '/path/to/your/folder')
```